# How to show table rows based on URL parameter

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

Currently the page is accessed using a link, for instance `help.html?show=charInPw`.

The table is written in the following manner:

```
<table>
    ...
    <tbody class="table-body">
        <tr class="pwLen"><td colspan="5" class="subheading">Password Length</td></tr>
        <tr class="pwLen"><td class="first">Minimum length</td><td>Y</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Y</td><td>Y</td></tr>
        <tr class="pwLen"><td class="first">Maximum length</td><td>Y</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Y</td><td>Y</td></tr>

        <tr class="charInPw"><td colspan="5" class="subheading">Characters in Password</td></tr>
        <tr class="charInPw"><td class="first">Minimum numeric characters</td><td>Y</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Y</td><td>Y</td></tr>
        <tr class="charInPw"><td class="first">Minimum alphabetic characters</td><td>Y</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Y</td><td>Y</td></tr>
...
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
table tbody tr{
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}
```

(There are also `tr`s in `thead` and they are always shown by default.)

Then I have some Javascript code as follows (jQuery is not an option):

```
<script>
    var url = new URL(window.location.href);
    var c = url.searchParams.get("show");
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName(c); i++)
        document.getElementsByClassName(c)[i].style.display='table-row';
</script>
```

However I am not able to get my rows to show.

How should I change the code on the page to show only the rows referenced by the `show` parameter?

---

Edit #1: As a test I did the following hard-coding but it didn't work too!

```
<script>
    var url = new URL(window.location.href);
    var c = url.searchParams.get("show");
    var trs = document.getElementsByClassName('pwLen');
    for (i = 0; i < trs.length; i++)
        trs[i].style.display='table-row';
</script>
```

---

Edit #2: I have combined two solutions below into one - please see https://jsfiddle.net/tea45p2o/. The demo output shown is what I want, however I am not able to see that when I save the file and open the page in my browser. What is going on?

Comment: #2 is an other question, it seem about your URL method, maybe you should use localStorage

Comment: @MrJ The code you see in the jsfiddle is the source inside my help file. However, I cannot get my help file to show the same output as the demo output in the jsfiddle. Unless by localStorage you mean something else?

Comment: I have no idea what the action of saving the page is for you, then re-reading it, there are a thousand ways to do it, and I can not guess the one you use; but anyway it's a completely different question from the previous one, and if you want an answer you have to create another topic with this question, and formulate it in a more precise way than here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With much help from BJohn and MrJ, I have come up with my solution as follows:

```
<script>
function show() {
    var url = new URL(window.location.href);
    var c = '.' + url.searchParams.get("show");
    for (let el of document.querySelectorAll(c)) el.style.display = 'table-row';
}
</script>
```

Then, I changed my `<body>` to

```
<body onLoad="show();">
```

Answer (score 0):

ŷou are missing to place **.length**
`for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName(c)`**.length**`; i++)`

But I think it would be more readable on this way

```
for(let TR_x of [... document.getElementsByClassName(c) ]) {
  TR_x.style.display='table-row'; 
}
```

but I definitely prefer

```
document.querySelectorAll('.'+c).forEach(trX=>{ trX.style.display='table-row' })
```

Comment: I tried your approaches but they didn't work. I added a small edit in my post. Not sure why that code snippet doesn't work.

Comment: YES that is what I want to see! However I am not able to get that to show in my browser!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
   for (let el of document.querySelectorAll(c)) el.style.display = 'table-row';
```

You also need to append dot (.) with class name, which you are getting from the URL.

[Please find the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/92rcaey0/)

Comment: I've edited my post again, combining your approaches into one jsfiddle, but no idea why I can't get that output.

Comment: @user10931326 did you tried with appending dot (.) in class name?

Comment: @BJohn yes, please refer to my jsfiddle. The code there is what I have. At this point I'm not sure if it's due to the positions of the codes in the page.

Comment: @MrJ John's code was wrong only because he used `block` instead of `table-row`. Just to clarify, both of your approaches work when I put them in the jsfiddle demo.

Comment: @user10931326 Really glad to know that it helped you.